# Upgrade to squeeze and dpkg returned an error code(1)

Tags: aptitude, dpkg

I want to upgrade my server so I ran `apt-get dist upgrade` but I keep having this error:

```
Unpacking replacement aptitude ...
dpkg-deb: file `/var/cache/apt/archives/aptitude_0.6.8.2-1_armel.deb' contains ununderstood data member data.tar.xz     , giving up
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/aptitude_0.6.8.2-1_armel.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of aptitude, which would be broken by installation of aptitude-common ...
dpkg: yes, will deconfigure aptitude (broken by aptitude-common).
Unpacking aptitude-common (from .../aptitude-common_0.6.8.2-1_all.deb) ...
De-configuring aptitude ...
dpkg-deb: file `/var/cache/apt/archives/aptitude-common_0.6.8.2-1_all.deb' contains ununderstood data member data.tar.xz     , giving up
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/aptitude-common_0.6.8.2-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2



Errors were encountered while processing:                                       
 /var/cache/apt/archives/aptitude_0.6.8.2-1_armel.deb                           
 /var/cache/apt/archives/aptitude-common_0.6.8.2-1_all.deb                      
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here's some of what I've tryied:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo ldconfig
sudo apt-get check
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get -f upgrade --fix-missing
```

Always ending with the same errors so I can't do anything else.

What should I do?

Comment: Exactly what sort of "server" is this? And, where are the rest of the error messages?

Comment: I'm using a [Guru Plug](http://www.globalscaletechnologies.com/t-guruplugdetails.aspx) . I added previous errors to the question. Thanks

Comment: I also have this warning: `WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  aptitude aptitude-common apt-utils libapt-pkg4.12 apt`

Comment: Reinstall from scratch?

Comment: @MichaelHampton question updated =)

Comment: What version of dpkg do you have? "dpkg --version" will show you

Answer (score 4):

You are updating your system to Debian wheezy (current stable), not to squeeze (oldstable) as you wrote in the title of the question.

I guess that you have a pre-squeeze system (Lenny, Etch, ...). So you are skipping at least one version. This is not supported and the reason why dpkg cannot unpack the package files (because of the 'new' .xz compression).

The solution is to update stepwise: So for Lenny, first to squeeze and then to wheezy. A fresh installation of the whole system might also be an option.

If your system is really old, you might have troubles to find the next newer version on the regular download servers. Use then http://snapshot.debian.org .

Comment: xz compression is new in wheezy?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Not exactly. Dpkg supports xz since Debian Squeeze. But it is actually used since Wheezy, so Squeeze system (but not older ones) can be upgraded to Wheezy. Changes in the package format can only become effective in the release after the changes was done, otherwise there is no upgrade possibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dpkg -r aptitude_0.6.8.2-1_armel
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

[Fix broken package](http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-debian/15825-ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution)

[Fix apt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195950/package-system-broken-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1)

Comment: I tried that and got the same... well. when I tried for the second time I got `dpkg - warning: ignoring request to remove aptitude-common_0.6.8.2-1_all which isn't installed.` which is obvious, but trying to install again led me to the error in the quetion

Comment: are u able to install any other package using apt-get?

Comment: No. I can't install anything now.

Comment: try http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-debian/15825-ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not providing a real answer. This is just a pointer *towards* the solution, as nobody seemed to see it.

The error message states that the package inside the DEB file is not a

```
.tar.gz
```

, but a

```
.tar.xz
```

This means it has been compressed using lzma. If apt/dpkg may be informed of how to unpackage those files, it should do the trick.